Change accent color on Ubuntu 24.10
I just upgraded my PC from Ubuntu 24.04 to Ubuntu 24.10. Everything is fine until, I added a few extensions using extension manager utility. When I'm trying to change the accent color to "Blue" I'm still on ugly Yellow border on dark theme. 
Also, please look at the sidebar, even after I tried to change it to blue, it won't change.
Please let me know, if you need additional info .. and please help, I'm trying to figure out it for almost 3-4 hours and still couldn't figure out :(

Hi, did you resolve the issue?

Unfortunately, no

@PRATAP just saw your website, noticed that just like me you're also from Andhra Pradesh. I would like to have a quick word with you. Would you mind if I send you an email?

Try uninstalling Gnome Tweaks. Also, turn off the user themes extension.

I had followed the steps .. but unfortunately, it didn't work :(
